# javascript multiplying with decimal points

Tags: javascript, validation

my **MultiplyChk validation** works nicely but the moment I use a decimal point it stops working.
Validation on 1st example works but not on the 2nd example.
both checks are multiplication validations. Can somebody help me please?

```js
function formValidator() {
    var Two = document.getElementById('Two'); //Category
    var Total = document.getElementById('Total'); //Category
    var ExVAT = document.getElementById('ExVAT'); //exVAT
    var AmtPaid = document.getElementById('AmtPaid'); //AmtPaid

    if (MultiplyChk(Two, Total, "Total Amt must be double the first amount",
            "The first calculation is correct, click OK for 2nd calculation")) {
        if (isVAT(ExVAT, AmtPaid, "incorrect or validation not working correctly", "YES! Correct!")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function MultiplyChk(elem, elem2, helperMsg, correctMsg) {
    if ((elem2.value) == (elem.value * 2)) {
        alert(correctMsg);
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function isVAT(elem, elem2, helperMsg, correctMsg) {
    if ((elem2.value) == (elem.value * 1.14)) {
        alert(correctMsg);
        return true;

    } else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form  action="alert('Correct!');"  onsubmit="return formValidator()" >
    This one works:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Two" name="Two" value="2"> *  2 =
    <input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" value="4">
    <br><br>
 
    but this validation does not work:<br><br>
    eg. R100 ex VAT = R114incl VAT<br>
    Ex VAT: <input type="text" id="ExVAT" size = 7 name="ExVAT" value="10">        <br>
    *1.14 = <br>
    AmtPaid: <input type="text" id="AmtPaid" name="AmtPaid" value="11.4">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit/Save"  onsubmit='return formValidator()'  style="width:300px;height:30px" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how *floating point numbers* work. Theyre not exact. So you need to have a small tolerance e.g.:

```
if(Math.abs(elem2.value-elem.value*2)<Number.EPSILON){
```

[about EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON)

or using a direct tolerance amount:

```
 if(Math.abs(elem2.value-elem.value*2)<0.0001){
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/zatezafozo/edit?output)

Comment: Hmm. Looks complicated. Sieht kompliziert aus. Is there a solution - maybe using rounding? Answers dont need to be perfect.

Comment: @clark superman naja, so kompliziert ist das doch gar nicht ... ;) , runden wäre zu ungenau z.B: (0.3-0.2) wäre gerundet auch 0 ...

Comment: Must I now integrate the EPSILON number into the formula so that it works?